# Detail about the "super" wildcard in java generics

Tags: java, generics, super

I have a question regarding generics:

```
Map<? super String, ? super String> mappa1 = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
```

with super it's possible to instantiate a `HashMap<Object,Object>` for a `<? super String>`.
However then you can add only objects which extends String ( in this case only String itself).
Why don't they forbid by compilation error as well as happens with the `extends` wildcard.
I mean if once created a `Map <Object, Object>` it's possible only to add Strings.. why not forcing to create a `Map<String, String>` in the first place? (like it happens with the `extends` wildcard)

Again I know the difference between `super` and `extends` concerning generics. I would like just to know the details I have aboved-mentioned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: However then you can add only objects which extends String ( in this case only String itself)

You can add CharSequences and Object, not objets which extends String.

Comment: @Nimajen it's mentioned in the question.

Comment: sorry, wrong key. My comment was incomplete.

Comment: @Nimajen you cannot add Object

Comment: What does it mean "Why don't they forbid by compilation error as well as happens with the extends wildcard"? You can write similar constuct with `extends`: `Map<? extends Object, ? extends Object> mappa1 = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Comment: @axtavt I was clearly referring to <Object, Object> try it out with "extends"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<? super String, ? super String> mappa1 = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
```

Since Java Generics are based on type erasure, with this line you didn't create a `MashMap<Object,Object>`. You just created an instance of the `HashMap` class; the type parameters get lost immediately after this line of code and all that stays is the type of your `mappa1` variable, which doesn't even mention `Object`. The type of the `new` expression is assignment-compatible with the type of `mappa1` so the compiler allows the assignment.

In general, the type parameters used with `new` are irrelevant and to address this issue, Java 7 has introduced the *diamond operator* `<>`. All that really matters is the type of `mappa1`, which is is `Map<? super String, ? super String>`; as far as the rest of your code is concerned, this is the type of the instantiated map.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html However in the that link it says: <Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.>

Comment: Furthermore in the case of the "extends" wildcard it should have been allowed as well. Intead it's not possible to create a HashMap<Object,Object> if the reference is Map<<? extends String, ? extends Strings>.

Comment: I know but still the compiler checks it. So there is a control in the instantiation.

Comment: As I said, the compiler makes sure the RHS is assignment-compatible with the LHS. I also point out that this check is irrelevant and just a nuisance; hence the *diamond operator*.

Comment: you said: "The type of the new expression is assignment-compatible with the type of mappa1 so the compiler allows the assignment." Basically I would like to know why since you then cannot add an Object in there.

Comment: I think what you are really asking is, why Java has wildcard types at all. The answer is, to make the generic type system more flexible while maintaining type safety.

Comment: Not really just knowing why it's allowed to add a List<Object> in a ? super <String> (which makes sense as an Object is a supertype of a String) and then it does not allow you to put Objects in that list. That's all. I know what the wildcards are for and how to use them. It was just a conceptual detail.

Comment: But you have posed exactly that question a couple of days ago; I answered; and you accepted. NB I have worked on that particular approach to explaining the type bounds for many years and couldn't possibly improve on it.

Comment: And thanks to your answer again. I here wanted just to know a language design specification which I think 'd rather ask to oracle itself eheh. Thanks for your time however.

Comment: Ok Marko I got what I was looking for.. I thought about it and the answer is very simple: it must be to guarantee polymorphism. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

Let's use `List` instead of `Map` for brevity.

Essentially, practical meaning of `extends` and `super` can be defined as follows:

- `List<? extends T>` means "a `List` you can get `T` from"
- `List<? super T>` means "a `List` you can put `T` into"

Now you can see that there is nothing special about `extends` - behavior of `extends` and `super` is completely symmetric:

```
List<? extends Object> a = new ArrayList<String>(); // Valid, you can get an Object from List<String>
List<? extends String> b = new ArrayList<Object>(); // Invalid, there is no guarantee that List<Object> contains only Strings

List<? super String> a = new ArrayList<Object>(); // Valid, you can put a String into List<Object>
List<? super Object> b = new ArrayList<String>(); // Invalid, you cannot put arbitrary Object into List<String>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are thrown off because you picked a collection type. Collections are rarely used as consumers and thus a lower bound (`? super X`) is not put on their element types. A more appropriate example is predicate.

Consider a method such as `<E> List<E> filter(List<? extends E> p, Predicate<? super E> p)`. It will take a list `l` and a predicate `p` and return a new list containing all elements of `l` which satisfy `p`.

You could pass in a `List<Integer>` and a `Predicate<Number>` which is satisfied by all multiples of `2.5`. The `Predicate<Number>` would become a `Predicate<? super Integer>`. If it did not, you could not invoke filter as follows.

```
List<Integer> x = filter(Arrays.asList(1,5,8,10), Predicates.multipleOf(2.5));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing doesn't exist.
It is because your reference is declared as `Map<? super String, ? super String>`. But your actual object can hold any object since it's `HashMap<Object,Object>`

```
 Map<? super String, ? super String> mappa1 = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
 map1.put("", "");

//you can put only string to map1

//but you can do this
 Map map2 = map1;
 map2.put(23, 234);
```

the same can be described by a better example:

```
String a = "a".
a.length(); // legal.

Object b = a;
b.length() // compilation error
```

Comment: It does not answer my question. I don't want to know a workaround for that. I would like just to know why it works like that

Comment: sorry, It is not a workaround, it is explanation. String is just an ordinary class in Java. Compiler doesn't care whether it is your Custom class or java.lang.String.